# Standard Technique /Algorithm for monitoring performance

Tags: java, monitoring, performance-testing

I am trying to monitor CPU / Memory process and etc.

Are there studies or article on the approach of monitoring such systems?

For example..

Duration it stays above 80% before sending an alert.... and after an alert.. under what circumstances it will be resolved and etc.

Is more of an literature review rather than jumping into the implementations aspect.

Project is written in Java

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Standard API for Java you can use [Java Management Extensions JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html) to monitor various server metrics. Oracle offers a good [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/). There are various implementations and you should research them on your own. If you are already using [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html%E2%80%8E) in your applicaiotn you could try their built in support. I have heard good things from people I work with about the [Sigar](https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) version (I am not affiliated with them in any way).

Comment: I know I can but I am talking about the algorithm deal with different type of monitoring.

Comment: What different types?